# can I show Instagram's business account's media in a react native app?

Tags: react-native, instagram-api

I want to show my own business instagram account's photos in a react native app, user dont need to sign-in to watch those images. I only want to fetch a few images and show them in a list, if the user clicks on them he will be redirected to the insta app. If anybody know how to fetch images please tell in detail. I have tried facebooks documentations but they are difficult to follow.